# How to fix slow running SSIS package

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I am trying to insert large amount of data from one table from PROD DB to table in Archive DB. Tables are with the identical schema and archive table is with drooped indexes and "Identity insert on". I need to insert only records that not exists in the Arh DB/Table.
I am using "Execute SQL Task" in SSIS sequence package and it works very very slow (using 20000 insert batch size).I have 20000 records inserted for 10 minutes.Just to mention I need to insert 48000000 records.
SQL server is 2016 standard edt.
Is there some solution for this.

The SQL query is :

```
SELECT TOP (@InsertBatchSize) s.ID,.....and other columns 
FROM PRODDB.dbo.source_table AS s WITH (NOLOCK) 
    INNER JOIN ArchiveDB.dbo.MissingIDsTable AS t WITH (NOLOCK) 
    ON s.ID = t.ID 
WHERE s.ID not in (SELECT ID 
                   from ArchiveDB..destination_table 
                   WHERE IsUpdated is null )
```

Comment: 20K rows should take seconds. Don't use "Execute SQL" to move data. That's the same as simply executing a SQL query or stored procedure. Moving data is the job of dataflows. As for moving changed rows only, how do you detect that the rows changed in the first place? With a LEFT JOIN? Using a stored ID value? Using change tracking?

Comment: If you use "Execute SQL" the delay is caused by the query, not SSIS. What does the query do? Where does it take its data from?

Comment: First I am inserting missing ID's into one physical table on ARH_DB side.This is working fast.
Also I have flag into Arh_table named isupdated and I am updating this flag with value 1 when I am update columns that are already inserted(and this step is ok).
Destination(Archive table) has Default constain 1 on inserting new record named IsInserted.

Comment: ----Bellow is the code for selecting the data that should be moved--------
SELECT TOP (@InsertBatchSize) s.ID,.....and other columns
FROM PRODDB.dbo.source_table AS s WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN
     ArchiveDB.dbo.MissingIDsTable AS t WITH (NOLOCK) ON s.ID = t.ID
WHERE s.ID  not in (SELECT ID from  ArchiveDB..destination_table WHERE IsUpdated is null )

Comment: Post the code in the question itself. Although it's obvious you've already found out the query is slow and tried to fix this the wrong way. `NOLOCK` doesn't mean "don't take locks", it means "don't respect others' locks, read dirty data and take extra lockes yourself"

Comment: That `WHERE IsUpdated is null` is *guaranteed* to result in slow queries. Even if it was covered by an index, that field can only have two values. The server will probably scan the entire table even if there is an index. You're scanning 48M rows to find those 20K rows to move

Comment: I guess there's a problem there, but I have no other way of isolating the data that needs to be inserted

Comment: Is there way of using other executable instead of Execute SQL task that will speed up the insert.

Comment: You do, but you still haven't posted any information about the tables. If you only copy new rows, you could only select rows with an ID greater than the MAX(ID) in the target table

Comment: You can use [Change Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) in the source database and detect insertions, updates *and* deletions.

Comment: You can avoid blocking if you use a Dataflow with a source query that doesn't involve the *target table. SSIS will take care of batching, and insert the data into the target using bulk operations. You can *remove* the `IDENTITY` attribute from the target tables, since the key data always comes from the source table

Comment: This can help I will try with max(ID) and I will avoid "not in (SELECT ID 
                   from ArchiveDB..destination_table 
                   WHERE IsUpdated is null )"   .Thanks i will inform you if this works better. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Execute SQL` isn't suitable for data transfer. It can't batch data, nor transform them. That's the job of Dataflow tasks. A Dataflow tasks allows reading source data using a firehose cursor and writing them to a data target using batched bulk operations using minimal logging. Its speed depends on the source query though. A slow query will result in slow execution.

The question is missing a lot of information, like the table schemas both in the source and target database. From `"Identity insert on"` I suspect the tables have an ID column that is an IDENTITY and primary key in the source. If you only care about new records, you can write a source query that only reads data since the last execution, eg :

```
SELECT s.ID,.....and other columns 
FROM PRODDB.dbo.source_table AS s
where ID>@maxId
```

Where `@maxId` is a query parameter supplied to the source query. There's no need for batching, SSIS can do that based on the data source, target settings for batch size etc.

This query should only be used for loading *new* data. To make the initial copy use a different dataflow whose source query doesn't filter anything. Using something like `Where ID>-1` would return all data but only after scanning the entire index. Why do *that* when we're already going to copy all the data?

The ID should be a primary key in the *target* table as well. This will speed up the `select MAX(ID) from target` operation that loads the parameter's value. It will also detect and prevent the inevitable duplication errors. No matter how careful we are, others always make mistakes that can result in duplicate data.

You can improve import performance by disabling the index before insertion and reenabling it after the import operation.

That's just one way you can detect changes and copy data. Another technique is to enable [Change Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) in the source table and retrieve rows modified since the last job run.

You could also copy modified data into a staging table and join *that* with the target to INSERT/UPDATE changes. The ID or change tracking can be used to find the modified data. This has the benefit of freeing up the source quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Task - data transfer between databases, target DB is located on SQL 2016 server.
I would recommend the following approach:

1. Create in ArchDB tables for staging load. Better to create it in separate schema and with the same names as original tables, just for management and readability.
2. Create a SSIS package with following steps:

   - Clean up necessary staging table in Exec SQL task
   - Data Flow task - move all data from Source to staging table in ArchDB. On the data flow - define a Lookup component with full cache based on ArchDB target table; this component will check records for existence in ArchDB. Pick up only missed records.
   - Move data from staging table in Arch DB to target table like

   INSERT INTO  WITH (TABLOCK) SELECT ... FROM

Comments:

- Lookup component in DFT serves for filtering out existing records. Since you do not have any indexes on ArchDB target table, you have to use Full cache with cost of high RAM footprint.
- `INSERT WITH (TABLOCK)` constriction is used to utilize parallel insert feature of SQL 2016.
- You can go without staging tables and do insert right into target table. However, debugging will be more difficult.

Comment: A lookup task for 48M data? That's essentially what the OP already did with the `MissingIDsTable` table. In fact the MissingIDsTable  is better, as it probably contains only the actual mismatches.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, Why not? If only ID is used for lookup, 1 row with bigint will be about 16 bytes, 48M * 16 bytes ~ 0.8 GB. Author has no indexes on ArchiveDB. This cache will do the same as `NOT IN` part of the query.

Comment: Because that job was already done when the `MissingIDsTable` was calculated. 800MB is a *lot* of RAM that's no longer available for buffering rows. If SSIS runs on the server, it's 800MB that are no longer available for SQL Server's use. Finally, that lookup is little different than what SQL Server itself would do with a JOIN, eg to an `AllTargetIDs` table. The server would be able to manage memory in a far better way though

Comment: If you *know* that the ID field is incrementing, and don't expect updates and deletions, you *know* that any changes in the source can only have an ID greater than the MAX(ID) of the target.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, According to the query, `MissingIDsTable` is some kind of filter; the filtered data is then checked for existence in `destination_table`. If no indexes - get ready for table scans and sorts for merge/hash joins with disk/TempDB ops on SQL side. If you have RAM and performance is a concern -- SSIS can do some things.